# Angular ApexCharts - Bar chart data not coming as expected

Tags: angular, typescript, charts, apexcharts, ng-apexcharts

I have used [ApexCharts](https://apexcharts.com/angular-chart-demos/) in my Angular 16 application.

Here my response is not appending on the chart. Please help me to modify the API response.

Response from API:

```
let data = [
  {
    tenantName: 'Station',
    labelName: 'aaaa',
    total: 7,
  },
  {
    tenantName: 'GERMANY',
    labelName: 'Application',
    total: 10,
  },
  {
    tenantName: 'GERMANY',
    labelName: 'Packages',
    total: 5,
  },
  {
    tenantName: 'Station',
    labelName: 'Security Features',
    total: 4,
  },
  {
    tenantName: 'Station',
    labelName: 'Setup and Configuration',
    total: 11,
  },
  {
    tenantName: 'Station',
    labelName: 'Speed',
    total: 9,
  },
  {
    tenantName: 'Station',
    labelName: 'WIFI signal Range',
    total: 21,
  },
];
```

I need to modify my response with `labelName` with count.

For Example:

> `tenantName` : Station and `labelName`: 'aaaa' with `total` is 7

But it is not working properly。

[image]

Tried code:

```
let labels = [...new Set(data.map((x: any) => x.labelName))];
let tenants = [...new Set(data.map((x: any) => x.tenantName))];
let subLabels = data.reduce((acc: any, cur: any) => {
  if (
    acc.findIndex(
      (x: any) =>
        x.tenantName == cur.tenantName && x.labelName == cur.labelName
    ) == -1
  )
    acc.push({
      tenantName: cur.tenantName,
      labelName: cur.labelName,
      total: cur.total,
    });

  return acc;
}, [] as { tenantName: string; labelName: string }[]);
```

[Demo link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-oafu6h?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I inspect in your chart with the data, you are looking for [Grouped bar chart](https://apexcharts.com/javascript-chart-demos/bar-charts/grouped/) with y-axis: `labelName` and each y-axis (category) contains multiple groups by `tenantName`.

You should group by `tenant` with each `tenant` object contains `name` field with `tenant` as value and a `data` array containing the value based on `tenantName` and `labelName`.

```
this.barChartData = tenants.map((tenant: any) => {
  return {
    name: tenant,
    data: labels.map(
      (label) =>
        data.find((y) => y.tenantName == tenant && y.labelName == label)
          ?.total
    ),
  };
});
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nq9tgp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)